# Type where the output of a function in a array is equal to the input of the next function in the array. Array of unary functions

Tags: typescript, generics, recursion, types

I am trying to declare a type that ensures that the output to a function in the array is equal to the type of the input to the next function in the array.

Example array:

```
const mappings = [
     (x: EditorState) => editorState.getCurrentContent(x) as ContentState,
     (x: ContentState) => convertToRaw(x) as RawDraftContentState,
     (x: RawDraftContentState) => JSON.stringify(x) as string,
     (x: string) => gzipString(x)
 ]
```

The type most likely has to be both recursive and generic

---

EDIT:

A solution in which all possible cases are covered for a list up to a certain length would suffice.

This should be possible right?

Comment: There is no such type; the closest you can get is a generic type to validate that a chain of functions is correctly written. See the linked q/a for more info.

Comment: Please see the edit of my question @jcalz. Now my question is different from the other question.

Comment: Feel free to vote to reopen the question, I don't have the ability to reopen it.